# Node.js and Forever / Forever-Montior

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, forever

I am currently using forever-monitor to spawn a basic HTTP Node Server, although when I execute the JavaScript that executes the forever-monitor scripts, it isn't sent to the background, when I exit the TTY session, the HTTP server stops.

The code I am using to spawn the server follows.

The question I am asking really is, should I be using Forevers CLI to spawn the script that spawns subsequent servers programatically?

```
var forever = require('forever-monitor');

  var child = new (forever.Monitor)('streams.js', {
    max: 3,
    silent: true,
    options: []
  });

  child.on('exit', function () {
    console.log('streams.js has exited after 3 restarts');
  });

  child.start();
```

Comment: This is a great question. Because this script is now the currently active TTY script. And only leads you down to recursion hell. Do you `forever` the `forever-monitor` script?

Answer (score 1):

You can either start that script with forever by running

```
forever start [your-script.js]
```

or if you don't want to install Forever's CLI you can just run

```
nohup node [your-script.js] > nohup.log &
```